# How i can set a default value in a cds view for a smarttable

Tags: sapui5, abap, cds

i have a question how i can set a default value in a cds view for a fiori elements app(based on annotations) what i tryed. I want to have the current date as a default value.

```
  @Consumption.filter: { defaultValue: '@Environment.systemDateTime' }
```

and also

```
  @Consumption.filter.defaultValue: '@Environment.systemDateTime')
```

and any other Enviroment date function.. and session

when i set in the default value a static value it work.

when i use the enviroment thing i get also the error

> One parameter has an invalid value: parameter IS_EXPRESSION-DATE has the invalid value

Answer (score 0):

you can try the sematic operator.
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/fef65d03d01a4b2baca28983a5449cf7

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@Consumption.filter.defaultValue
Works only for static value.
For dynamic value use

> @Consumption.derivation

Refer: https://sapabapcentral.blogspot.com/2018/09/date-function-for-dynamic-date.html